# Winston 3 + Loopback: Error messages are shown in access.log

Tags: loopbackjs, winston

I am using Winston (3.0.0rc5) within loopback. I have the following Winston.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */
'use strict';

var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');
const {colorize, combine, timestamp, printf} = winston.format;

// Define your custom format with printf.
const timeStampFormat = printf(info => {
  return `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
var options = {
  info: {
    format: combine(
      timestamp(),
      timeStampFormat
    ),
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/access.log`,
    handleExceptions: false,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
  },
  error: {
    format: combine(
      timestamp(),
      timeStampFormat
    ),
    level: 'error',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/error.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
  },
  console: {
    format: combine(
      timestamp(),
      colorize(),
      timeStampFormat
    ),
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
  },
};

// instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
var logger = new winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.info),
    new winston.transports.File(options.error),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console),
  ],
  exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

module.exports = logger;
```

The error.log and access.log files are created just fine. The error.log is not showing any info messages as expected. However, the access.log file does show error messages even though I have set handleExceptions to false.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like handleExceptions is for uncaught exceptions, not logged errors:
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#handling-uncaught-exceptions-with-winston

Perhaps this problem could be solved by creating custom logger levels with the standard levels except error, like this:
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#using-custom-logging-levels

FYI - there is an issue similar to this:
https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/614